# excel equation to find corresponding value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I hope if some body can help me with this, i tried many search over last week but i could not figure it out

what i need: i have large excel data file with many column i am interested about column AG and column AH

I want Equation to pick up the first cell in column AG when value in Column AH less than 0.3

note : column AH start with 0.4 value then this number get smaller

i appreciate you help

Comment: Can you provide some sample data on your question? And perhaps some indication what are you trying to get since I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to achieve. First Cell on AG, when AH is less than 0.3? You mean to return the value of AG1, or return the value of AGn when AHn < 0.3?

Comment: i mean returning to AGn when value of AHn less rhan 0.3

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you can use the [`IF` function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx). This function performs a logical test, then returns a value if its true or false.

```
IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

So if the check of `AH2` is less than `0.3`, then it returns `AG2`.

```
=IF(AH2<0.3, AG2,"")
```

*(The `""` simply returns a blank cell if the check is false. Otherwise, it returns a `0`. )*

Once you have the formula working the way you like, you can copy it down the column.

Comment: i mean returning to AGn when value of AHn less than 0.3

Comment: @fahad this solution will work for that.

Comment: I tried =IF(AH2<0.3, AG2,"") but give me empty value!!!!

Comment: What is the value of `AH2`? If is is 0.3 or higher the cell where the formula is will be empty.

Answer (score 1):

The formula below should be what you are looking for.

```
=INDEX(AG2:AG27,MATCH(MAX(IF(AH2:AH27<0.3,AH2:AH27,0)),AH2:AH27,0))
```

**A few things to note:**

1. After entering the formula hit **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** instead of just enter
2. This assumes your data is in AG2:AH27. You'll need to adjust the formula to match your data source

**Here is a breakdown of what is happening**

=======

```
MAX(IF(AH2:AH27<0.3,AH2:AH27,0))
```

This bit finds the maximum value that is less than .3

=======

```
MATCH(MAX LESS THAN .3,AH2:AH27,0)
```

Combined with the MATCH formula it finds the row number that the value is found in

=======

```
=INDEX(AG2:AG27,FOUND ROW NUMBER)
```

Combined with the INDEX formula it now locates the corresponding value in column AG based on the row of the desired number in AH.

Comment: I think you got your `G`s and `H`s reversed – the OP wants the value from the first `AG` row where the `AH` value is less than 0.3.

Comment: Good catch @Scott. I've edited to swap them around.